# Include path not working for C debugger in VSCode - Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, vscode-debugger

I am using VS Code remote via SSH to Raspberry Pi for my first C project.  The code compiles without a problem, but the debugger can't find the header files.  I have reviewed existing [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079599/includepath-in-c-cpp-properties-json-not-working-in-vscode-for-c) but the suggested solutions are not solving my problem.

If I place the header file in the root of my project, the file is found by the debugger.

Source, line 18:

```c
#include "mfrc522.h"
```

The file is available in `include` folder:
[image]

tasks.json:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "--include-directory=${fileDirname}/**",
                "--include-directory=${fileDirname}/include/**",
                "--include-directory=${fileDirname}/src/*/*.c",
                "--include-directory=${fileDirname}/*.c"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/*",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/*/*.c"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/include/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/src",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/src/*",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/src/*/*.c"
                ]
            },
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Resulting error:

> main.c:18:10: fatal error: mfrc522.h: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.

Comment: "the debugger can't find the header files" --- what do you mean exactly? What kind of error do you see?

Comment: Why not SSH into the raspberry pi and invoke the debugger there?

Comment: @t0mm13b This is via SSH

Comment: `"--include-directory=${fileDirname}/**",` and `"--include-directory=${fileDirname}/include/**"` are wrong for gcc.  This documentation explains how to add an include directory: [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, I'll read the linked document!  I want to include all src and header files, even if in a deeper directory.  At the moment I can point the debugger only at a specific directory and contained directories are ignored.

Comment: `-I "${fileDirname}/include",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70836878/10340388) by **bko** earlier, which seems to have overcome the issue of including the header files.

> What solved it for me was to just type folder path without /* or /** Then it prompted me if I want to enable Intellisense for this folder and I allowed it and it worked.